# Backbone.js app completely rendered in JS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

I'm trying to build a new project in Backbone.js, having come from a background developing webapps in Java, PHP, Rails, Perl, and so on. I've done a quite a bit of JS stuff, including JQuery and some Node, but I'm having a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around the best practice for building entire apps in Backbone. It seems like the stuff in the tutorials tends to differ from how I see real-world applications implemented.

I've been reading Addy Osmani's [Backbone Fundamentals](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/). His examples have you create a static HTML file into which you put the skeleton of the app, which is then modified by JS. An example snippet:

```html
  <section id="todoapp">
    <header id="header">
      <h1>todos</h1>
      <input id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
      <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
      <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer"></footer>
  </section>
```

This is all well and good, and seems like a decent enough approach. But I've seen several apps in the wild where the static HTML file is just a handful of stylesheets and script tags. And it would appear that the entire application is then generated by the JS. This seems beneficial for apps that have a lot of different views with dynamic content.

I'd really like to understand how these apps are built, but I've been unable to find documentation or tutorials that cover it. I think I could hack something together, but I'd really rather understand the proper way to do it, best practices, etc.

Can someone point me in the direction of some docs to learn about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question but unfortunately quite open-ended. There are [many](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/backbone-express-spa) [such](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/64) [tutorials](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/single-page-todo-application-with-backbonejs--cms-21417) [around](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spa%20backbone.js), but I'd rather answer by giving you a high-level overview of what needs to be done.

The distinction to which your question refers is *where* the rendering of HTML takes place: all on the server side, all on the client side, or a mixture of both.

Another (related) question is *where* **routing** takes place.

The closest to an "all client side" approach is one in which there is one server-side user-facing URL endpoint that returns a small HTML response that is essentially a bootstrapper for the client side, as in this example:

> GET /

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Loading</title>
    <script data-main="/client/main" src="/client/libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This uses the AMD module-loader `require.js` (there are many other choices, but bear with me). In turn, `require.js` will automatically load the script specified in `data-main`, in this case, `/client/main.js` (the `.js` is not included by convention).

> GET /client/main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/client',       // this tells require to load things relative to this "base" path
    paths: {
         underscore: 'libs/underscore',
         jquery: 'libs/jquery',
         backbone: 'libs/backbone',
         text: 'libs/require-plugins/text',      // this is a "plugin" for require.js that allows you to load textfiles instead of scripts when you precede the path with 'text!'
         // etc for other libs
    },
    shim: {
         underscore: { exports: '_' },
         jquery: { exports: '$' },
         backbone: { deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'], exports: 'Backbone' }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'application'], function($, Application) {

    var $rootDiv = $("<div>", {id: "app-root", class: ""});
    $('body').prepend($rootDiv);
    var app = new Application({ rootEl: $rootDiv });
    app.start();

});
```

I don't want to delve too much into `require.js` specifically, so I'll just note that it does what it looks like it does: it loads JavaScript asynchronously and in a controlled fashion (so you say *this* script depends on *that* script, etc.). The first block is just configuration for `require.js` and is somewhat beside the point, but I wanted to make this realistic.

The second block is more interesting. Here's what it says:

1. `require` the following dependencies: `jquery` and `application`
2. After loading them (either from an `HTTP GET` or from a cache if loaded before), alias them as `$` and `Application` respectively.
3. Create a new `div` and prepend it to `body`.
4. Create a new `Application` specifying the `rootEl` as the `div` created
5. Call `start` on the application instance.

Here's what the DOM looks like at this point:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Loading</title>
    <script data-main="/client/main" src="/client/libs/require.js"</script>
    <script data-requiremodule="main" src="/client/main.js"></script>
    <script data-requiremodule="jquery" src="/client/libs/jquery.js"></script>
     <!-- ... etc ... -->
     <script data-requiremodule="application" src="/client/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="application-root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now about that last dependency, `application.js`:

> GET /client/application.js

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'backbone', 'text!templates.html'], function(_, $, Backbone, Templates) {

    var getStartOptions = function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        _(options).defaults({
            rootEl: $('body'),
            initialRoute: '/'
        });

        return options;
    };

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.state = new Backbone.Model(getStartOptions(options));

            this.listenToOnce(this.state, 'change:started', function() {
                this.state.set(getStartOptions(options));
            }, this);

            this.listenTo(this.state, 'change:rootEl', this.onChangeRootEl, this);
        },
        onChangeRootEl: function(val) {
            this.setElement(val);
            if (!this.state.previous('rootEl')) {
                var $templates = $('<div>', {id: 'app-templates'});
                $templates.html(Templates);
                $('body').append($templates);
            }
            this.render();
        },
        template: _.template($('#app-templates #app-layout-template').html()),
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        },
        start: function() {
            this.state.set('started', true);
        }
    });

});
```

The `define` function is like `require` (it's part of `require.js`) but it doesn't "run" by itself - `require` does. So, whatever you `define` you must `require` elsewhere to run.

The `return` value from the `define` function argument is what you get back when you `require` it.

In this case, `getStartOptions` is *private* but the `View` returned is the value of requiring `['application']` from before.

Roughly what happens is as follows:

1. From before, we instantiate the `View` defined here (we call it `Application`)
2. We call `start`
3. `start` sets `started` to `true`
4. When `started` is true, the view (through the `listenToOnce` call) sets the initial options.
5. The first time we set a `rootEl` we inject templates into the `DOM`.
6. When options change, we update the view accordingly and then re-render.

After all this the result would be:

```
<body>
    <div id="app-root">
        ... content of the template with id "app-layout-template" ...
    </div>
</body>
```

The layout template just needs to be in this kind of form.

> GET /client/templates.html

```
<script type="text/whatever-you-want" id="app-layout-template">
...
</script>

<script type="text/x-underscore-template" id="example-of-app-layout-template">
    <header><h2><%= appTitle %></h2></header>
    <section><%- appContent %></section>
    <footer><p><%= appFooterMessage %></footer>
</script>
```

[Here is some information about underscore templates.](http://braddunbar.net/2013/08/19/underscore-templates/) There are many other choices out there.